# How to convert magnetometer readings into orientation?

Tags: sensor, localization

I have a magnetometer sensor, obtaining the reading with $50$Hz rate. Unfortunately, the data is not labeled: I just know that these are $x$,$y$,$z$ axes, and that the reading are in $\mu$T (micro Tesla). How can I obtain from this data the orientation of the sensor board (in relation to north pole) in degrees or radians?

Comment: Are those magnetic field readings in 3D? Vectors? What model you use? part number?